# pdfcrop will not work in 11.10

Tags: 11.10

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 pdfcrop will not work. It runs and produces a file, but the product is exactly the same as the original, with no cropping.  Has anyone else noticed this? and does anyone know of a fix?

Answer (score 1):

pdfcrop (v0.4b) relies on pdfedit & will silently do nothing if pdfedit is not installed.  You can install pdfedit as:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfedit
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at this thread in which there are some useful infos:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11383090